# Write into a file the summary report in r

Tags: r, file-io, summary, rpart

I am using the rpart function for building a recursive partition regression tree (test2) of variable Y using the predictors X1,..., X6. I would like to write the (formatted) summary information that is printed when calling `summary()` into a text file.

as an example this is what I would like to have in the output file:

```
> cont.parms.Y <- rpart.control(minsplit=10,cp=0.011)
> test2 <-rpart(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6,cont.parms.Y)
> summary(test2)
```

[print screen of the desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZ9Hx.jpg)

When I type `write.table(matrix(test2),file='output.txt')` I get a mesh of the output results, as you can see on the image linked.

Could you help me please?

Comment: Use `capture.output()` to record the output in a character vector, then writeLines()` to write it to a file.

Comment: Just looked at `?capture.output`, it has a `file` argument so you actually don't need `writeLines` at all.

Comment: Thank you so much Gregor! I appreciate the help